# Textfield with Animated Label/Hint for Suggestion

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

Is there a way to animate the textfield label text/hint text to show suggestive phrases for the user?
I saw few examples on Instagram and G.pay search textfields

Ex:
The textfield label should animated **search "Jeep"**, **search "Car"** etc..